# A simple way to update values on webpage served by ESP8266

Tags: c++, forms, arduino, html, esp8266

I have a web page with a form to set some times. I have the page stored in flash and I want to update the times from the previously saved values in eeprom. I don't want to load the page into ram. I want to send the page and then update the times with a second operation. I don't want to use websockets and I prefer not using AJAX.

I was hoping there was a simpler method. Maybe a GET request? And somehow link that to the variables in the form.

The code I have is below. I have found one AJAX with JASON example that did what I needed. I figured it all out after some work. I'm thrilled that I now have that in my bag of tricks. But I was hoping for something simpler.

I have considered looking at HTML5 Server-Sent Events. I have not figured it out but it is supposed to be simpler than AJAX. I thought I could serve the page and then, a short time later, send the values to populate the times in the form. Because of the "short time later" it seems a bit clunky. I was hoping that I could initiate it by the server with something like onload.

````
```static const char PROGMEM relayTimesHTML[] = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Set relay on and off times</title>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/saveTimes" >
<br>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Clock timer control:</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="timerEnabled" value="timerDisabled" checked> Timer Disabled
  <input type="radio" name="timerEnabled" value="      timerEnabled"> Timer Enabled<br>
  <br>

  Turn On time: <input id="onTime" type="time" name="on_time" value=01:17 ><br><br>

  Turn Off time: <input id="offTime" type="time" name="off_time" value=02:23 ><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myForm").elements["onTime"].value= "03:33";
document.getElementById("myForm").elements["offTime"].value= "04:00";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
)rawliteral";
```
````

I want the value of onTime/on_time to be changed to the real current value in the ESP. A simple method to replace the the current value.

Also. I don't understand a lot about the DOM and how to change things, but I think I know enough to maybe get it done right. The script section I have in the code is how I think I will need to modify the times. I just need to somehow get the times into that.

I'm not a programmer, I'm a hardware designer. All the programming stuff is challenging for me.

[image: input form to modify]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is honestly the simplest way to do this.

AJAX is simply Javascript issuing an HTTP request to a web server to pull over a fragment of data. That fragment could be HTML, JSON, or just a bit of text.

As you mentioned, another option is [HTML5 Server Side Events](https://medium.com/conectric-networks/a-look-at-server-sent-events-54a77f8d6ff7). Server Side Events are a little more difficult for the server to handle than AJAX is. With AJAX, the server just takes care of a normal HTTP request and is done. With Server Side Events, the server must keep the client's HTTP connection open and continue to service requests from that connection. They're basically an ongoing stream of AJAX requests over an HTTP connection that's held open. It's a little more housekeeping and overhead for the server.

If this matters to you, [Server Side Events are not yet supported under Microsoft browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource) (of course this may change in the future).

Another possibility is WebSockets, but again, that's more work for the server, and they're also built over AJAX. If you want to try them, there are WebSocket libraries available for the ESP. They're unlikely to be let your code be simpler than AJAX would.

There are other protocols like UDP the ESP could use but they're not accessible from Javascript on a browser, so they're non-starters.

So you're left with AJAX.

However, there's no need need to use JSON or XML or any other specific representation with AJAX. AJAX is agnostic about the format of the data it moves. So you can just return the value you want as a fragment of text and not worry about creating and parsing JSON.

I'd also recommend checking out [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for manipulating the DOM. It's a very well supported and widely used and compatible Javascript library for the browser which greatly simplifies manipulating the DOM. If your browser will always have a live Internet connection you can load jQuery from a content distribution network and not worry about serving it from the ESP.

jQUery can also simplify issuing AJAX requests.

Comment: "Another possibility is WebSockets, but again, that's more work for the server, and they're also built over AJAX." From what I have read Websockets has nothing to do with AJAX, but I do agree with you that it is more complex that I would like for this application.   I didn't know that SSE was not supported by Edge, so that alone kills that possibility.     I guess AJAX is the way to go.   Using Json (on the client side) was pretty easy when I finally figured it out.  I want to understand Javascript better so I am going to pass on jQuery for now.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is to reload the whole webpage at n-seconds.
After the `<html>` tag, add:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='30'/>
```

The browser will now reload the page at every 30 seconds.
You'll have to change the timer values in the page-layout yourself (ESP-side).

If you want (preferrable) update only certain parts of the website, you do need AJAX or equivalent techniques.

GET and POST is how you send the formdata back to the server.

Comment: Reloading the page doesn't work because I am still reloading the page without modifications. Taking what is stored in flash memory without change to the variables. I want to show the user what the current values are rather than have them have to set the values each time they access the page. I know I can do it with AJAX.

Comment: I can't get your question clear: is scripting (AJAX/Server-Sent Events) a no-go?

Comment: My third paragraph said I figured out how to do it with AJAX but I wanted something simpler.